# Multiple value field makes Listing loop

Tags: profile, joomla, 4.7

I'm modifying `/templates/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.tpl` to a specific customer need. The profile I need to show using that includes a Multiple Value custom field.

When I tried the Listing with a record (Contact ID) with more than one value in that custom field, is shown multiple times that Contact ID, each one with one value from the Multiple Value custom field.

I turned debug on and the $rows array really shows multiple entries, each one with one value from the Multivalue field.

No matter if I turn `is_multi_summary => "1"` on or off, it doesn't change anything.

The code from Listing.tpl I'm working on looks like that:

```
  {foreach from=$rows item=row name=listings}
  <div id="row-{$smarty.foreach.listings.iteration}" class="{* cycle values="odd-row,even-row" *} ppindiv">

    <p class="crm-{$columnHeaders.2.field_name}">{$row.2}</p>
    <div class="crm-{$columnHeaders.1.field_name}">{$row.1}</div>
    <p class="crm-{$columnHeaders.5.field_name}">{$row.5}</p>
    <p class="crm-{$columnHeaders.7.field_name}">{$row.7}</p>

  </div>
  {/foreach}
```

Also, makes no difference if I use the original loop to show the values, like that:

```
  {foreach from=$row key=index item=value}
    {if $columnHeaders.$index.field_name}
      <p class="crm-{$columnHeaders.$index.field_name}">{$value}</p>
    {else}
      {* $value *} 
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
```

Things still got duplicated.

Is it possible to says Smarty to show the Multivalue Field only once, with all the values inside? Like a localized "foreach"?

Answer (score 1):

Answer or sort of.

First you cannot pass numbers as index ie. `$columnHeaders.1.whatever` smarty will print just `$columnHeaders`

Second, same applies for `$rows`, I guess it holds an array of arrays with perhaps an `id` for each array with the custom fields, or just an index, if that's the case you need to nest your loops.

Example:

```
{foreach from=$rows key=index item=row}
     {foreach from=$row key=field item=value}
        <p>{$field}: {$value}</p>
     {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Hope that gives you a hint and helps.